# A change in my library made it much slower. Profiling isn't helping me. What might be the reason for the slow-down?

Tags: haskell, profiling, ghc

## My Problem, Briefly

I made a change to my library, now it's much slower but I can't figure out where it spends all that additional time. Profiling reports are not helping. Please help me figure out what the reason might be.

## Some Context

I made a Redis client-library called [Hedis](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hedis) and have a benchmark program for it. Now, I made some internal changes to the library, to clean up the architecture. This caused performance (in Redis-requests per second, as measured by said benchmark) to drop by a factor of about 2.5.

The benchmark opens 50 network connections to a Redis server on localhost. The connections are handled differently between the two versions:

- **The fast version** uses one thread per connection (thus, the benchmark has 50 threads running concurrently). It reads from the socket
  handle by using `unsafeInterleaveIO` (I describe my approach in broad
  strokes in a [blog post here](http://informatikr.com/2012/redis-pipelining.html)). I was a bit unhappy
  with the architecture, hence I changed things to
- **the slow version** which uses three threads per connection. They communicate via two `Chan`s (150 threads running in the benchmark).

Some more information that might be relevant:

- Compiled with GHC 7.2.2.
- The benchmark program is unchanged between the two versions, so network
  traffic is the same.
- Both versions use the single-threaded runtime (compiled *without*
  `-threaded`).
- All threads are created by calling `forkIO`. *Not* the more expensive
  `forkOS`.

## Profiling Results

Profiling does not give me a clear reason for the drop in performance. According to the profiling report, both versions spend more than 99% of their time in `System.IO.hFlush` and `Data.ByteString.hGetSome`. The number of times `hFlush` and `hGetSome` are called is the same in both versions. Since network traffic is also the same in both cases, these functions can't be the reason for the slow-down.

The only significant difference I can measure between the two versions is what `time` (the Unix utility) tells me: the slow version (with three times as many threads) spends significantly more time in "sys" instead of "user", compared to the fast version. The GHC `+RTS -s` flag reports this as reduced productivity.

Here are the program outputs for both versions with the `+RTS -s` flag:

### Benchmark of the Fast Version

```
$ time ./dist/build/hedis-benchmark/hedis-benchmark +RTS -s -p
ping                   33305.29 Req/s
get                    25802.92 Req/s
mget                   18215.94 Req/s
ping (pipelined)      268994.36 Req/s
   5,118,163,904 bytes allocated in the heap
     185,075,608 bytes copied during GC
       4,084,384 bytes maximum residency (39 sample(s))
         916,544 bytes maximum slop
              10 MB total memory in use (0 MB lost due to fragmentation)

                                    Tot time (elapsed)  Avg pause  Max pause
  Gen  0      7416 colls,     0 par    0.38s    0.40s     0.0001s    0.0003s
  Gen  1        39 colls,     0 par    0.03s    0.03s     0.0007s    0.0009s

  INIT    time    0.00s  (  0.00s elapsed)
  MUT     time    7.93s  ( 12.34s elapsed)
  GC      time    0.41s  (  0.43s elapsed)
  RP      time    0.00s  (  0.00s elapsed)
  PROF    time    0.00s  (  0.00s elapsed)
  EXIT    time    0.00s  (  0.00s elapsed)
  Total   time    8.33s  ( 12.76s elapsed)

  %GC     time       4.9%  (3.3% elapsed)

  Alloc rate    645,587,554 bytes per MUT second

  Productivity  95.1% of total user, 62.1% of total elapsed


real    0m12.772s
user    0m8.334s
sys     0m4.424s
```

### Benchmark of the Slow Version

```
$ time ./dist/build/hedis-benchmark/hedis-benchmark +RTS -s -p
ping                   11457.83 Req/s
get                    11169.64 Req/s
mget                    8446.96 Req/s
ping (pipelined)      130114.31 Req/s
   6,053,055,680 bytes allocated in the heap
   1,184,574,408 bytes copied during GC
       9,750,264 bytes maximum residency (198 sample(s))
       2,872,280 bytes maximum slop
              26 MB total memory in use (0 MB lost due to fragmentation)

                                    Tot time (elapsed)  Avg pause  Max pause
  Gen  0      9105 colls,     0 par    2.11s    2.14s     0.0002s    0.0006s
  Gen  1       198 colls,     0 par    0.23s    0.24s     0.0012s    0.0093s

  INIT    time    0.00s  (  0.00s elapsed)
  MUT     time   10.99s  ( 27.92s elapsed)
  GC      time    2.34s  (  2.38s elapsed)
  RP      time    0.00s  (  0.00s elapsed)
  PROF    time    0.00s  (  0.00s elapsed)
  EXIT    time    0.00s  (  0.00s elapsed)
  Total   time   13.33s  ( 30.30s elapsed)

  %GC     time      17.6%  (7.8% elapsed)

  Alloc rate    550,656,490 bytes per MUT second

  Productivity  82.4% of total user, 36.3% of total elapsed


real    0m30.305s
user    0m13.333s
sys     0m16.964s
```

Do you have any ideas or hints where that additional time might come from?

Comment: Why are you using the single-threaded runtime?  I would be very surprised if the single-threaded scheduler is as heavily optimized towards concurrent workloads (like this one) as the multi-threaded version.  Even if you use the multi-threaded runtime, you can still restrict it to run on a single core if that's your concern.

Comment: By the way, in the non-threaded runtime, forkIO and forkOS are the same operation. In the threaded runtime, the only difference is that threads created with forkOS are guaranteed to make all native calls from the same system thread. That makes them mildly more expensive, but only in the case where they could be scheduled better without that restriction.

Answer (score 3):

According to the profiling report, most of the time is spent in `hFlush` and `hGetSome`.  According to `time`, the slow version takes a lot more sys time.  So, my hypothesis is that a lot of time is spent blocked and waiting, whether it's waiting for more input or locking and unlocking threads.

Here's the first thing I would do: compile the code with `-threaded` and see what happens.  The threaded runtime uses a completely different IO manager, and I strongly suspect that this single change will fix your problem.

Comment: I'd think "blocked  and waiting" time should count as idle time rather than as system time.

Comment: @Rotsor - maybe, it depends what its waiting for.  I don't know much at all about the single-threaded IO manager, or how that runtime handles concurrency, so I can't answer that.  The OP could run the program under `strace` or similar to try to find out.

Answer (score 2):

My *guess* would be that it's something to do with the overhead of `Chan`.

My first thought was increased GC time, but that doesn't appear to be the case at all. So my second thought is that maybe all the locking and unlocking involved in using `Chan` (which is implemented on top of `MVar`) is the problem. But this is still only a guess.

You might try `TChan` (i.e., STM) instead and see if that makes the slightest shred of difference. (Perhaps you could code up a small skeleton just to compare the two and see if that's where the problem is, rather than reimplement your "real" code.)

Other than that, I'm out of ideas.

Comment: I had a slightly different experience: my application was running out of memory under heavy load. I replaced TChan with [TBQueue](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/stm-2.4.4.1/docs/Control-Concurrent-STM-TBQueue.html) with small size (< 10). That did seem to help.